# IOS app background full size not cover full

Tags: html, ios, css, ibm-mobilefirst, phonegap

I am developing IOS app via phonegap with html and css

but background has issue.You can see in that attachment screen shot that bottom and banner there is black area occur altouhg image is enough big(1238*2208)

Here is my full html and css code below.And you can see here my full html page
http://trakya.hybridsoftware.net/Mobile1/index.html 
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
      <style>
     html{
        background: url('images/acilis-logo.png') 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
         background-size:cover;
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        -o-background-size:cover;

    }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="position:absolute;align:center; vertical-align:middle;top:90%" > 

  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="bottom:%24px;margin:">


      <div class="column1"><img onclick="SetTurkish()" title="Türkçe" src="images/turk-logo.png"></div>
      <div class="column1"><img onclick="SetEnglish()" title="English"  src="images/amerika-logo.png"></div>
      <div class="column1"><img onclick="SetGreece()"  title="ελληνικά"  src="images/yunan-logo.png"></div>

      <div class="column1"><img onclick="SetBulgarian()" title="български" src="images/bulgar-logo.png"></div>
    </div>

       </div>


</body>
</html>
```

what is problem with that code?

Comment: I think vertical-align:middle;top:90% ? Anyway is related to css

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the [viewport changes introduced in iOS 11](https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/). You'll need to do two things to solve this:

1. Update your viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

The above is an example, you may have to remove a couple of properties. You can also choose to use `viewport-fit=contain` if you don't want your app to extend over the whole screen.

2. Add splash screens to accommodate the larger screen sizes of the latest iOS devices. The easiest way to do this is to switch to new launch storyboard images, there is more information on how to do that in [the documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#single-image-launch-screen) of `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`.

You may also have to update `cordova-plugin-statusbar` to the latest version if that is included in your project. There is also more information about this [on the PhoneGap blog](https://blog.phonegap.com/displaying-a-phonegap-app-correctly-on-the-iphone-x-c4a85664c493).